# Rails 4 Update Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Updating Nested Attributes append instead of updating in has many relationships
I am trying to use Rails 4 Update_attributes

```
Class Person <ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :pets
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :pets
end

Class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :person
end
```

In my controller I am recieveing the params as
{id: 23, house_no:'22A', pets: [{name:'jeffy', type:'dog'}, {name:'sharky', type:'fish'}]}

and my update method is

```
def update
  @Person = Person.find(params[:id])
  if @Person.update(person_params)
    @Person.save
    render 'persons/create', status 200
  else
    render 'persons/create', status 400
  end
end

private
def person_params
  person_params = params.permit(:house_no)
  person_params.merge! ({pets_attributes: params[:pets]}) if params[:pets].present?
  person_params
end
```

Now when I update it 
and if the person already has a pet
then the new pets gets appended instead of getting updated
eg if a person with id 1 has 1 pet named "Tiger"
and I update that person with 2 pets named "Shasha" and "Monti" then the person record has 3 pets (Tiger, Shasha and Monti) instead of updating it to 2 (Shasha and Monti)

Comment: because it is has_many right?

Comment: yes, it properly updates the normal string attributes

Answer (score 19, accepted):

see the manual:

> http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

you need to send in your attributes like `pets_attributes:[{name:'jeffy', type:'dog'}, {name:'sharky', type:'fish'}]`

and it should work fine.

Please read

> You can now set or update attributes on the associated posts through an attribute hash for a member: include the key :posts_attributes with an array of hashes of post attributes as a value.For each hash that does not have an id key a new record will be instantiated, unless the hash also contains a _destroy key that evaluates to true.

Comment: This will only work if you have accidentally left the `:id` parameter which is crucial. In order to avoid duplicating put an `:id` in `pets_attributes`

Comment: if you're using Strong Parameters then you can rename `pets`   to `pets_attributes` after the `permit` stuff kinda like the OP's `merge` code, like this: `params[:pets_attributes] = params.delete(:pets) if params[:pets]` -- why ActiveRecord itself doesn't gracefully handle receiving a hash of attributes is beyond me :-/

Comment: agreed with pets_attributes but also need to add :id in the pets objects

Answer (score 26):

You have to add the `:id` attribute to the `:pets_attributes`
array in `person_params`.

You need to permit the id attribute to update the records.

Comment: This is the only actual correct answer. The `:id` is crucial. The `destroy` explanation also makes sense, but this actual answers the OP's question.

Comment: @Aleks so what is the difference between this and the `destroy` explanation? This worked for me but the latter is the one officially documented.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal How would you know which record you want to destroy? You need an `id` of it. Everybody mentions the `_destroy` but the OP asked how to **update**,and not destroy. If you would like to fix destroying as well, then you would certainly need to add `_destroy`, but for updating, an `id` is what you need.

Comment: this is the right answer when you need to update the records

Answer (score 16):

Update the `Person` model as below:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base  ## NOTE: class (c lowercase) and NOT Class
 has_many :pets
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :pets, allow_destroy: true  ## Added allow_destroy
end
```

In order to destroy the associated model i.e., `Pet` through the attributes hash, you have to enable it first using the `:allow_destroy` option.

Then, from your view, you will need to pass the `_destroy` attribute for the pets that you would like to be removed.

Since, you haven't shared the view specific code. Following is an example of how it should be implemented in your view. Change it according to your requirement:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%## .. %>  
  <%= f.fields_for :pets do |builder| %>
    <%## .. %>    
    <%= builder.check_box :_destroy %>
    <%= builder.label :_destroy, "Remove Pet" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In the above code, you would need to add the `checkbox` and `label` for passing `_destroy` value.

After this, update the `person_params` method in your controller as below:

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:house_no, pets_attributes: [:id, :name, :type, :person_id, :_destroy])
end
```

**NOTE:**

You **should not** be defining `instance variables` with **capitalized** name. Capitalized names are used for declaring `Constants` in `Ruby`.

```
def update
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  if @person.update(person_params)
    @person.save
    render 'persons/create', status 200
  else
    render 'persons/create', status 400
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit you params with pets_attributes

Also need to add :id paramter in the pet objects.

Answer (score 1):

Probably 1. you would want to assign pets separately,

```
@Person.pets = Pets.find(params[:pets])
```

Or 2. clear the pets before saving Person.

```
@Person.pets.destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `person_params` as

```
def person_params
  person_params = params.require(:person).permit(:house_no ,pets_attributes: [:name,:type])
end
```

And remove `@person.save` from the update method.You don't need it.And also use `!` for `update`

```
def update
  @Person = Person.find(params[:id])
  if @Person.update!(person_params)
    render 'persons/create', status 200
  else
    render 'persons/create', status 400
  end
end
```

**Update**

And also,as i can see there is no `belongs_to :person` association in `Pet` model,Add it in the model

```
Class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :person

end
```

And now permit the `person_id` attribute by adding it in the `params`

```
def person_params
  person_params = params.require(:person).permit(:house_no,pets_attributes: [:name,:type,:person_id])
end
```

Comment: For the first change in params.require(:person).permit(:house_no) it gave 
  ActionController::ParameterMissing:   param not found: person  and even after adding the bang and removing the person.save it still updates it to 3 pets instead of 2

Comment: It still gave me 3 pets

Comment: @Pavan I want to "create" in update method of person. what i meant is Person might update but if i fill pet, it should create new.