# Nested models with simple_form and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, simple-form

[This maybe a simple issue, but I just can't find a solution]

I'm trying to update an existing record with new data and add some image(s) to that record (via paperclip), however, my code doesn't show the `paperclip` field at all.

[I've followed this example](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models#an-example) and also tried with [this solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492873/rails-4-update-nested-attributes), but nothing works.

I have two, models `Hotel` and `HotelImage`.

**hotel.rb**

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :location, presence: true

  has_many :hotel_images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hotel_images

  def slug_candidates
    [
      [:name, :location],
    ]
  end
end
```

**hotel_image.rb**

```
class HotelImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotel

  #rails generate paperclip hotel_image image

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @hotel, :url => admin_hotel_path, method: :put, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :location %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :hotel_images do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.input :image, as: :file %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**hotels_controller.rb**

```
#other code

def update
  @hotel = Hotel.friendly.find(params[:slug])

  if @hotel.update(hotel_params)
    redirect_to admin_hotels_path, notice: 'Hotel was successfully updated.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
 end

private

def hotel_params
  params.require(:hotel).permit(:name, :location, :admin_id, hotel_images_attributes: [:hotel_id, :image])
end
```

Here's the print screen of the form, where you can see that the paperclip field is missing:

[image: preview]

---

However, when I change `f.simple_fields_for :hotel_images` to, for example, `f.simple_fields_for :foobars`, the paperclip field is shown:

[image: example2]

---

**Note**: the `name` and `location` attributes update just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def update
  @hotel = Hotel.friendly.find(params[:slug])
  if @hotel.update(hotel_params)
    redirect_to admin_hotels_path, notice: 'Hotel was successfully updated.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

def edit
  @hotel_images = @hotel.hotel_images.present? ? @hotel.hotel_images : @hotel.hotel_images.build
end
```

Try this code

Comment: The paperclips field still doesn't display.

Comment: Yea, that's it. I forgot to update the edit method :stupid_me: . Thanks :)